# Usage of for loop and if statement in bash

Tags: bash

I am using the following code but the final 'echo $dirname' is giving empty output on console

for folderpath in `find /u01/app/SrcFiles/commercial/ngdw/* -name "IQ*"`;
do
folder_count=`ls -d $folderpath/* | wc -l`
echo -e "Total Date folder created : $folder_count in $folderpath \n"

```
if [ $folder_count -ne 0 ];
then
    for dirpath in `find $folderpath/* -name "2*" `;
    do  
        dirname=${dirpath##*/}
        (( dirname <= 20210106 )) || continue
        echo $dirname 
        
    done
fi
```

done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would calculate the date it was 3 months ago with the `date` command:

```
# with GNU date (for example on Linux)
mindate=$(date -d -3month +%Y%m%d)

# with BSD date (for example on macOS)
mindate=$(date -v -3m +%Y%m%d)
```

Then I would use a shell arithmetic comparison for determining the directories to remove:

```
# for dirpath in "$directory"/*
for dirpath in "$directory"/{20220310,20220304,20220210,20220203,20210403,20210405}
do
    dirname=${dirpath##*/}

    (( dirname <= mindate )) || continue

    echo "$dirpath"
    # rm -rf "$dirpath"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` doesn't do wildcard matching. You should do that in the `for` statement itself.

There's also no need to put `*` at the beginning of the wildcard, since the year is at the beginning of the directory name, not in the middle.

```
for i in "$directory"/202104*; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "$i"
        rm -rf "$i"
    fi
done
```

The `if` statement serves two purposes:

1. If there are no matching directories, the wildcard expands to itself (unless you set the `nullglob` option), and you'll try to remove this nonexistent directory.
2. In case there are matching files rather than directories, they're skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to find which are the directories that created before 90 days ago or older, with `find` command.

```
 find . -type d -ctime +90
```

If you want to find which directories created 90 --> 100 days ago.

```
 find . -type d -ctime -100 -ctime +90
```

Once you have the correct folders list. Feed it to the `rm` command.

```
 rm -rf $(find . -type d -ctime +90)
```